# Description obout Qualities of Human Mind and Advice for Mind , from Ancient Hinduism texts?

Tags: scripture, puranas, philosophy, mind, book-recommendation

In Which ancient writtings  , Shlokas , Books we find more description about Human Mind ? eg. description of Human Mind's characteristics , qualities, It's strength and weakness etc.?

What texts gives advice to our mind and guides us about our good behaviour in society? For example , A 15 th century saint from western India (Deccan) named "Ramdasa" written a book advising our mind. Name of the book is "Manache Shlok" Or Shlokas for Mind.

Note- Although all our texts including Gita is grand advice to ourselves ,our mind. I want specific writtings about Human Mind.And my question is more philosophical rather than scientific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is mind according to Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/what-is-mind-according-to-hinduism)

Comment: How about Yog Sutras and Raja Yoga?